# Generate binary code to each class in deep learning model and hash it

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

Hope to find you doing well,

I have a deep learning model(CNN -RNN) with multi-class classification and I want to generate maximum entropy binary code, each class has unique binary code and assign this code to each class In the training phase, and during the training, I want to hash this binary code.. as in “ MaximumEntropy Binary Encoding for Face Template Protection“ paper

How can I make it in [python](/questions/tagged/python)?

Comment: can you give an example to make this clear? also some pseudo code will be helpful

Comment: I see this part in “ MaximumEntropy Binary Encoding for Face Template Protection” paper , section 2.2 and 2.3 ..and I want to program it in python

Comment: A link to the paper will be helpful, also include it in the question so others can also answer, along with something you have tried doing or thought of doing, if possible

Comment: I read the paper and if I am not wrong, a face is given a binary code and a CNN is trained to map a face to that binary code. You can use any framework like keras, pytorch etc to train the network with n bit output labels(which have already been assigned) and a softmax activation for output layer. The hashing will happen afterwards when you convert the output to a quantized bitstring. You can do the hashing using hashlib or similar library and save the known hashes.